# Laravel in docker: cannot run migrations - access denied for root user

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to contenairize my laravel application (not using their default docker config `sail` for reasons not in the scope of this question). The containers (app, server and db) seem to be built and run correctly, but when I try to run the database migrations:

`docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate`

I'm getting the following error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.28.0.4' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = dundermifflin and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

This is my service configuration in `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
db:
    image: mysql:8.0.31
    container_name: dmc-db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    # use the variables declared in .env file
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: abcd1234
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - dmc-net
```

And this are the vars defined in `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
# use mysql container name instead of 127.0.0.1 when running in docker, otherwise use the IP
DB_HOST=dmc-db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=dundermifflin
#DB_USERNAME=michaelscott
DB_USERNAME=root
#DB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD="7aADMi__Cfv"
#DB_PASSWORD=root
```

If I connect to the container and then try running:

`mysql -u root -p`

using the password defined above (`abcd1234`) I get the same error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'192.168.0.4' (using password: YES)`

Every single time I make any change to the vars or to `docker-compose.yaml` I'm running `docker-compose build --no-cache` just to make sure none of the old configuration vars stick around.

What am i missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried runing command with more options? (especially with db name)

```
mysql -u root -p dundermifflin
```

also try maybe without defining `MYSQL_HOST` and then

```
mysql -u root -p dundermifflin
```

or
mysql -h localhost -u root -p dundermifflin

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connecting.html